# Puppet virtual resource not realized

Tags: puppet

I have the following virtual resource declared outside of all classes in a module init.pp

```
@sensu::check {
    "check_postgres_backup":
         command => "/etc/sensu/plugins/check_postgres_backup.rb",
         interval => "36000",
         subscribers => ["psbackup"];
}
```

I then try and realise it in another module using

```
class sensu::server::virtual {
    realize Sensu::Check[check_postgres_backup]
}
```

But I get the following error

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to realize virtual resources Sensu::Check[check_postgres_backup] on node ######.######.co.uk
```

SOLUTION:

Well it seems that anything outside of a class is undefined and so can't happen so this solution won't work at all.

I got around the problem by using sensu standalone checks instead which means I can define all the checks on the modules for the services they are checking.

Comment: Usually instead of using realize I'd want to use `Sensu::Check <| |>` so that it would find all my virtual resources but that fails silently.  I'm using realize because that actual puts an Error if it fails.

Comment: sorry, no idea.  Try it with the correct case on the realize maybe?

Comment: From the documentation. https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_collectors.html#syntax you have to capitalize the name of the resource that you are trying to realize.

Comment: Cool, your question just taught me a keyword I didn't even know. Are you including the class that has the virtual resource?

Comment: @ChrisPitman the virtual resource isn't included in a class.  From the documentation: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_virtual.html#virtual-resources-in-classes It says you only have to include a class if you define a virtual resource in the class.

Comment: So it is declared in a random module's init.pp, but not in a class with the name of the module? I've never done that before, but does puppet even know to autoload that init file if there is no reference to it?